# How to keep sentinel value from entering loop

Tags: python

My sentinel value of -99 keeps entering my while loop and displaying as my smallest output. How do I either delete it as a variable or keep it from entering the loop?

```
variable = []
def main():
 userInput = input("What are your numbers? (Follow by -99) ")
 numberInput = [int(x) for x in userInput.split()]
 variable.append(numberInput)
# print(variable)
 count = 0
 while count < len(variable):
   count += 1
   if numberInput == -99:
     break
 larger = max(numberInput)
 smaller = min(userInput)
 print("The highest number is", larger, "and the smallest number is", smaller, ".")


main()
```

Comment: what exactly are you doing? why are you using `min()` on string

Comment: You should probably use None as your sentinel value. Would require refactoring numberInput to parse a string none and set that k/v to None. userInput is a string...you should be doing min(numberInput) as well.

Comment: `numberInput = [ ... for ... in ... if x != -99 ]` or `numberInput.remove(-99)`

Comment: BTW: check `print( variable )` - you create nested list `[ [ value, ...] ]` so `len(variable)` will be always `1`. You need rather `variable = numberInput`

Comment: BTW: if user put `-99` as last number then `count = len(numberInput) - 1` and you don't need loop. If user put `-99` before other numbers then `count = numberInput.index(-99) -1` and then you can skip numbers after `-99` using  `numberInput = numberInput[:numberInput.index(-99)]`

Comment: Frankly, I would get all number which user put in `input()` without cheking `-99` or `none`

Comment: I agree with @furas: `[int(x) for x in input("enter a list of numbers: ").strip().split() if x.isnumeric()]` seems to work and if you need to get multiple lists you could just use it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    userInput = input("What are your numbers? (Follow by -99) ")
    numberInput = [int(x) for x in userInput.split()]

    for i in range(len(numberInput)):
        if numberInput[i] == -99:
            del(numberInput[i:]) 
            break
                 
    larger, smaller = max(numberInput), min(numberInput)
    print("The highest number is", larger, "and the smallest number is", smaller, ".")


main()
```

Here is a fixed solution to your problem as is. Will edit with a None sentinal. The problem is you were not deleting from numberinput the sentinal -99. I removed extraneous variables, if you need them for outside the problem they should be easy to re-add. Simple to convert your sentinal:

```
def main():
    userInput = input("What are your numbers? (Follow by \'none\') ")
    numberInput = list()
    
    for x in userInput.split():
        if x != "none": numberInput.append(int(x))
        else: break
        
    larger, smaller = max(numberInput), min(numberInput)
    print("The highest number is", larger, "and the smallest number is", smaller, ".")


main()
```

However I thought this would work, however a commenter said breaks in list comprehensions are not allowed.

`numberInput = [int(x) for x in userInput.split() if x != "none" ]` doesn't stop the iteration. I don't know why in 3.8.2 if else in comprehensions isn't working but theoretically:
`numberInput = [int(x) if x != "none" else break for x in userInput.split()]`

Output:

```
What are your numbers? (Follow by 'none') 10 20 30 none 5 40
The highest number is 30 and the smallest number is 10 .
```

Comment: in second version you forgot to convert strings to integers.

Comment: `break` inside list comprehension is not allowed in all versions. List comprehension can't use `statements` like `break`, `return`  or assignments `a = 1` (or `print` in Python 2). If you want to break then you have to use normal `for`-loop.